# Error at line 3/16: ORA-00942: table or view does not exist

Tags: oracle, oracle-apex, oracle-apex-5.1

i get this error whenever i try to run this trigger when i try  to assign a working schedule for an employee and when i assign the working schedule to this employee from the master table in the details table it should generate for me the working schedule details table based on the working schedule id in the working schedule page but i dont know how to do it and i need assistance
TRIGGER:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE TRIGGER TRG_INSERT_EMPLOYEE_WORK_SCHEDULE
AFTER INSERT ON EMPLOYEE_WORK_SCHEDULE_testtt
FOR EACH ROW
DECLARE
    v_new_id NUMBER;
BEGIN
        
    -- Generate a new unique ID for each detail record,
    SELECT NVL(MAX(ID), 0) + 1 INTO v_new_id FROM EMPLOYEE_WORK_SCHEDULE_DETAIL_testtt;
    
    -- Inserting into detail table, modify the columns and values 
    INSERT INTO EMPLOYEE_WORK_SCHEDULE_DETAIL_testtt (ID, ...other columns...) 
    VALUES (v_new_id, ...other values...);
    
    -- You can add more logic if needed
END;
/
```

And This Is The DLL FOR both table

Master Table:

```
  CREATE TABLE "EMPLOYEE_WORKING_SCHEDULE_testtt" 
   (    "ID" NUMBER, 
    "EMPLOYEE_ID" NUMBER NOT NULL ENABLE, 
    "WORK_SCHEDULE_ID" NUMBER NOT NULL ENABLE, 
    "ASSIGNMENT_DATE" DATE NOT NULL ENABLE, 
     PRIMARY KEY ("ID")
  USING INDEX  ENABLE
   ) ;

  ALTER TABLE "EMPLOYEE_WORKING_SCHEDULE_testtt" ADD CONSTRAINT "FK_EWS_EMPLOYEE" FOREIGN KEY ("EMPLOYEE_ID")
      REFERENCES "EMPLOYEES" ("EMPLOYEE_ID") ENABLE;
  ALTER TABLE "EMPLOYEE_WORKING_SCHEDULE_testtt" ADD CONSTRAINT "FK_EWS_WORK_SCHEDULE" FOREIGN KEY ("WORK_SCHEDULE_ID")
      REFERENCES "WORK_SCHEDULE_MASTER" ("ID") ENABLE;

  CREATE OR REPLACE EDITIONABLE TRIGGER "EMPLOYEE_WORKING_SCHEDULE_TESTTT_T" 
after
insert or update or delete on "EMPLOYEE_WORKING_SCHEDULE_testtt"
for each row
begin
    null;
end;
/
ALTER TRIGGER "EMPLOYEE_WORKING_SCHEDULE_TESTTT_T" ENABLE;
```

DETAILS TABLE:

```
  CREATE TABLE "EMPLOYEE_WORKING_SCHEDULE_DETAIL_testtt" 
   (    "ID" NUMBER, 
    "EMPLOYEE_WORKING_SCHEDULE_ID" NUMBER NOT NULL ENABLE, 
    "DAY" NUMBER NOT NULL ENABLE, 
    "DAY_MODEL" VARCHAR2(50 CHAR) NOT NULL ENABLE, 
    "SHIFT_DEFINITION_ID" NUMBER NOT NULL ENABLE, 
     PRIMARY KEY ("ID")
  USING INDEX  ENABLE
   ) ;

  ALTER TABLE "EMPLOYEE_WORKING_SCHEDULE_DETAIL_testtt" ADD CONSTRAINT "FK_EWSD_EWS" FOREIGN KEY ("EMPLOYEE_WORKING_SCHEDULE_ID")
      REFERENCES "EMPLOYEE_WORKING_SCHEDULE_testtt" ("ID") ENABLE;
  ALTER TABLE "EMPLOYEE_WORKING_SCHEDULE_DETAIL_testtt" ADD CONSTRAINT "FK_EWSD_SHIFT_DEFINITION" FOREIGN KEY ("SHIFT_DEFINITION_ID")
      REFERENCES "SHIFT_DEFINITIONS" ("ID") ENABLE;
```

Tried to run but it wont work

Comment: Use an identity column or a sequence as @Littlefoot suggests. If consecutive numbers are needed, then check this stack overflow [answer](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=B5JltFoe5Ho).

Answer (score 1):

As you decided to enclose table and column names into **double quotes**, now you have to do it **every time** you reference those names, matching letter case.

In trigger, you didn't do it so it failed because table with that name really doesn't exist - in data dictionary, its (table's) name is stored in mixed case. By default, if you don't use double quotes, all identifiers are stored in uppercase, but Oracle lets you reference them any way you want.

I'd suggest you to

- drop tables
- remove all double quotes
- recreate tables
- create trigger

---

But, that's not all you did wrong. It seems that you really misspelled table name.

- `create table` suggests that table name is `EMPLOYEE_WORKING_SCHEDULE_testtt`, while
- trigger is created on `EMPLOYEE_WORK_SCHEDULE_testtt`

---

That's still not all: that's a row-level trigger and - in it - you're selecting from the same table:

```
AFTER INSERT ON EMPLOYEE_WORK_SCHEDULE_testtt      --> this
FOR EACH ROW
...
SELECT NVL(MAX(ID), 0) + 1 INTO v_new_id 
FROM EMPLOYEE_WORK_SCHEDULE_DETAIL_testtt;         --> this
```

That will lead to a mutating table error.

There's a way out (actually, two - using a package or a compound trigger), but - generally - that bad idea altogether. It might work in a single-user environment, but imagine 10, 20 or more users concurrently accessing that table, firing the trigger and all of them getting the same `V_NEW_ID`. That's a **primary key** column, you can't have duplicates.

What to do?

- if your database supports it, use an **identity** column
- if not, use a **sequence**

  - if database supports it, use it as column's default value
  - if not, create a `before insert` trigger which will put sequence next value into the `ID` column